# Vertical scroll in IE8 on 1024 * 768 resolution

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, responsive-design

am developing page every thing working fine, I need it to be responsive almost every thing is working fine but vertical scroll coming in `IE8 on 1024 * 768 resolution`, How to sole that please help me

```
<div class="container">
<div class="header">
<div class="header-bg">
<div class="wrapper">
<a class="logo" title="Olympic Industrials Logo" href="#"></a>
<div class="menu-menu-container">
   <ul class="menu" id="menu-menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13" id="menu-item-13"><a href="#/" title="Home">Home</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-156" id="menu-item-156"><a href="#">Catalogue</a></li>
      <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-10 current_page_item menu-item-15" id="menu-item-15"><a href="#/quote/" title="Quote">Quote</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>              
</div>      
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="sibebar-menu-container">
<div class="mob-menu-link"><a id="moblink" href="#"></a></div> 
<div class="inner-sidebar">
  <ul class="quote_list">
    <li>
      <span class="quote_rightquote">“</span>
      <p class="quote_sidepara1">Olympic Industrial, manufacturers of speacial maintenance tools and garage equipment, was establisg in 1978</p>
    </li>
    <li>
      <p class="quote_sidepara2">Olympic proud to be appointed as the supplier to Daimler India for their commercial vehicles</p>
      <span class="quote_sidepara2img"></span>
    </li>
   </ul>            
</div>
<div class="footer">
<div class="wrapper-container">
<a class="develop" target="_blank" href="indiainternetready.com/"></a>

</div>

</div>      
</div>

<div class="left-content">

<div class="breadcrum_products">

<p class="breadcrum_headertext">Request form</p>

</div>

<div class="content-area  quote_content-area">

<div class="ctitle">Request for Quote</div>

<div class="ctxt">Fill out the below to request a quote on any tools and equipments. include information like part numbers of part descriptions. A sales representative is  going to contact you with the quote.</div>

<div class="form">

<ul>

<li><div class="err" id="nameerr"></div><input type="text" onblur="namevalidation(this.value);if(this.value==''){this.value='Name*';this.style.color='#AEAEAE';}" onfocus="if(this.value=='Name*'){this.value='';this.style.color='#7b7b7b';}" maxlength="50" value="Name*" id="name"></li>

<li><div class="err" id="emailerr"></div><input type="text" onblur="validateemail(this.value);if(this.value==''){this.value='Email*';this.style.color='#AEAEAE';}" onfocus="if(this.value=='Email*'){this.value='';this.style.color='#7b7b7b';}" maxlength="75" value="Email*" id="email"></li>
</ul>

<ul>

<li><div class="err" id="comperr"></div><input type="text" onblur="compvalidation(this.value);if(this.value==''){this.value='Company Name*';this.style.color='#AEAEAE';}" onfocus="if(this.value=='Company Name*'){this.value='';this.style.color='#7b7b7b';}" maxlength="75" value="Company Name*" id="compname"></li>

<li><div class="err" id="countryerr"></div>

<select id="country"><option style="color:#AEAEAE" value="-- Select Country --">-- Select Country --</option><option value="India">India</option><option value="Egypt">Egypt</option><option value="South Africa">South Africa</option><option value="Dubai">Dubai</option><option value="West Indies">West Indies</option><option value="Vietnam">Vietnam</option><option value="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option></select>

</li>

</ul>           

<ul>

<li><div class="err" id="mobnumerr"></div><input type="text" onblur="mobnumvalidation(this.value);if(this.value==''){this.value='Mobile Number*';this.style.color='#AEAEAE';}" onfocus="if(this.value=='Mobile Number*'){this.value='';this.style.color='#7b7b7b';}" maxlength="10" value="Mobile Number*" id="mobnum"></li>

<li><div class="err" id="faxerr"></div><input type="text" onblur="faxvalidation(this.value);if(this.value==''){this.value='Fax Number';this.style.color='#AEAEAE';}" onfocus="if(this.value=='Fax Number'){this.value='';this.style.color='#7b7b7b';}" maxlength="20" value="Fax Number" id="fax"></li>


</ul>

<div class="formtextarea">

<span class="pls">Please utilize this space to provide us with as much information you may have concerning your Request for Quote:</span>

<div class="err" id="msgerr"></div>
<textarea onblur="messagevalidation(this.value);if(this.value==''){this.value='Type your message*';this.style.color='#AEAEAE';}" onfocus="if(this.value=='Type your message*'){this.value='';this.style.color='#7b7b7b';}" id="comment">Type your message*</textarea>

</div>

<div class="checkboxarea">

<div class="quote_email">

<input type="checkbox" id="newsletter"> <span>Send me email news and updates from Olympic Industries.</span>

</div>

<div class="quote_sendbtn">

<a title="Send Quote" id="subid" href="javascript:postform()"></a>

</div>

</div>


<div id="succ-msgid"></div>

</div>

</div>

</div>
```

//css

```
.header {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-bottom: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
height: 81px;
left: 0;
padding: 0 0 3px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
z-index: 10000;
}
.sibebar-menu-container {
background-color: #1F1F1F;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 242px;
z-index: 9999;
}
.left-content {
background-color: #F5F5F5;
margin: 0 auto 0 242px;
padding-top: 62px;
width: 83%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add to css `body{margin:0; padding:0}`

and remove `width: 83%;` from `.left-content`